# Is it possible to sell not-in-stock products on Magento?

Tags: stock, stock-status

I would like to make it possible to order items which I don't have in stock, but it seems if I want to allow backorders, I must have the item listed as "in stock", which looks weird if people order it and then get the message that it's not in stock anyway.

Is there a solution to this problem? I would like to make it possible to add out-of-stock items to the basket and list them as as either "in stock" or "not in stock - delivery time 5-6 days". But I can't find a way to 1) allow not-in-stock goods to be put in the basket and 2) change "not in stock" to "delivery time 5-6 days".

Answer (score 5):

You can enable back orders in admin area go to

> Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Catalog Tab > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Backorders

And enable back orders

Answer (score 3):

If you want to enable this feature for a particular product thats also possible. Go to Catalog > Manage Products and edit the product you want to allow orders even when its out of stock.

[image: backorder]

As seen in the image above, click on inventory tab from left and change the settings of Backorders. Uncheck the checkbox User Config settings and than choose Allow Qty below 0.

Save the product and now this single product will be available for ordering even when its out of stock.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did. Only problem: It doesn't work!
I have to list the product as "in stock", otherwise it's not possible to add it to the basket. Even if backorders are allowed.