# Magento 2 is it possible to sell not in stock products?

Tags: magento2, out-of-stock

I wan't to make it so that when a product is out of stock a customer will stil be able to purchase it. The product must stil say "Out of stock" but with a purchase button so that it's clear to the customer that the product is stil out of stock.

I've read this answer but it seems to be outdated:

- [Is it possible to sell not-in-stock products on Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79266/is-it-possible-to-sell-not-in-stock-products-on-magento)

Comment: What should certainly be done when click on "add to cart" button on Out of stock product ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable backorder. This is Magento feature where you can allow the user to purchase the product even it is out of stock in the backend. But product is out of stock this will not display in thefrontend, product will always display in stock in the frontend. If you want to display out of stock status when product inventory is negative then you need to make customization.

You can use below tutorial to enable the backorder.
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html
https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-backorders/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I've already tried that and it's not what I'm looking for. I stil want my product to say "out of stock" in the product page. But with an "add to cart" button

Comment: Correct, as I said, you need to customize the in-stock and out of stock message only. Regarding add to cart button, it will display even product is out of stock.